# How to make images align side by side when fetch multiple images in a single column that belongs to the same category

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch multiple images from a single columns which belongs to the same category and I want this images to be lay side by side with their category. When I fetched the images with their category the category appeared number of times the images.

Take a look at the image below, ABUA appeared once in the user table but has three images in the upload table likewise Eksu which has two images. I do not want the display to be like this, I want the images to align side by side and the details appear once.

[image: Image 1]

My sql query is below:

```
<?php  
//Education
$e = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM education where fid = '$id' group by schools ");
while($edu = mysqli_fetch_array($e)){

  $eid = $edu['fid'];
  $sc = $edu['schools'];
    $now=mysqli_query($mysqli, "Select distinct * from uploads WHERE fid='$eid' AND category = 'education' and sch='$sc' order by '$sc' ");

    while($resultsn=mysqli_fetch_array($now)){
     $tempr = explode(',',$resultsn['img_name'] );

foreach($tempr as $imager){
$img = "<img src='../cert/".$imager."' class='img-thumbnail' width='50' height='50'/>";


        ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $img; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $edu['schools']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $edu['course']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $edu['qualification']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $edu['years']; ?></td>

</tr>

     <?php
     }

    }
   //}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 while($resultsn=mysqli_fetch_array($now))
{
   $tempr = explode(',',$resultsn['img_name'] );

   $imgs = '';
   foreach($tempr as $imager)
   {
    $imgs .= "<img src='../cert/".$imager."' class='img-thumbnail' style='display: inline-block;' width='50' height='50'/> ";
   }
   ?>

   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $imgs; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $edu['schools']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $edu['course']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $edu['qualification']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $edu['years']; ?></td>

   </tr>

<?php}?>
```

Comment: you are the best. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a table row for each one the entries in your second while loop. 
If you want the images side by side, you should create the table row inside your first loop and have only image `<td>` elements added in the second while loop.

After that loop is closed, echo the remaining `' elements inside the initial while loop to display the other fields of your table. You'll have one row with all images for that category instead of multiple rows.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this one:

<?php  
//Education
$e = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM education where fid = '$id' group by schools ");
while($edu = mysqli_fetch_array($e))
{

  $eid = $edu['fid'];
  $sc = $edu['schools'];

  $now=mysqli_query($mysqli, "Select group_concat(img_name) as img_name from uploads WHERE fid='$eid' AND category = 'education' and sch='$sc' order by '$sc' ");

  while($resultsn=mysqli_fetch_array($now))
  {

    $tempr = explode(',',$resultsn['img_name'] );

    foreach($tempr as $imager){
      $imgs += "<img src='../cert/".$imager."' class='img-thumbnail' width='50' height='50' style="margin-right:10px;"/> ";

    }

  }
  ?>

  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $imgs; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $edu['schools']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $edu['course']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $edu['qualification']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $edu['years']; ?></td>

  </tr>

<?php

}
?>
```